# How to create a view that functions like Alert in SwiftUI on watchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I want to have an alert style view that can include an icon image at the top along with the title.

[alert(isPresented:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(ispresented:content:)) used with [Alert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert) does not seem to support adding images in any way. However, other than that limitation, it functions as I want my alert to function. It covers the status bar and blurs the main view as the background for the alert.

I attempted to use [fullScreenCover(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) instead, but this approach does not behave like an alert as far as covering up EVERYTHING including the status bar, and blurring the main view as the background.

I have tried this so far, with the following result. One of the reasons I want it to behave like a normal Alert is so that the content can scroll without overlapping the clock time.

```swift
struct AlertView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataProvider: DataProvider

    var alert: Watch.AlertMessage

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Image("IconAlert")
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

            Text("Test Title")
                .bold()

            Text("Test Description")

            Button("DISMISS") { print("dismiss") }
        }
        .padding()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this this sample custom alert. It may give you some great approach(Code is below the image):

[image]

```
struct CustomAlert: View {
  @State var isClicked = false
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        Button("Show Alert") {
            withAnimation {
                isClicked.toggle()
            }
        }
        ZStack {
            if isClicked {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(.thickMaterial)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .transition(.scale)
                VStack {
                    Image("Swift")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                    Button("Dismiss") {
                        withAnimation {
                            isClicked.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                .transition(.scale)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which part of this would make this view cover the status bar clock, or create a blurred background?

Comment: @Dustin what device you want this to work on? watchOS, iOS or ?

Comment: I need a solution for watchOS 7+